# CNN text document classification with Keras: How to fit the model of "independent layers of two input"

Tags: python, keras, model, conv-neural-network

I have a CNN model that inputs two independent documents and do the convolutional layer and pooling layer separately. After pooling layer, it then concatenate two pooled feature maps together and feed to one fully connected layer. The model can successfully compiled. However, Now, **I have problem fitting my model when doing the train history.**

**Main idea of my problem is that: How to revise the x_train to x_train1 and x_train2. x_test to x_test1 and x_test2. While y_train and y_test remain the same.**

I've reference this kind of pattern from a site:

** history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100, verbose=False, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), batch_size=10)**

```
# fit the model method 1
train_history = model.fit(train_data = (X_train1, X_train2), 
                      validation_data=(x_test1, x_test2), epochs=8, batch_size=8, verbose=1) 

# =================

# fit the model method 2
train_history = model.fit(x = [x_train1, x_train2], y = [y_train], validation_split=0.2, validation_data=[[x_test1, x_test2], [y_test]], epochs=8, batch_size=8, verbose=1)
```

- The error massage of first method 1 is:

  > Unrecognized keyword arguments: {'train_data': (['.....'......}
- The error massage of first method 2 is:

  > ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have shape (10,) but got array with shape (1,)

**every kind of x_train and x_test data is a long list that contains many strings; whereas y_train and y_test is also a list the maps with the string in x_test/x_train to a specific label, the label looks like this if it were to classify into 3 types: [0,0,1], [0,1,0], [1,0,0]**

I expect to fit the model successfully.